# How can the BitCountry economy interact with other parachain?

Tags: polkadot, parachain

how can the Bit Country economy interact with other para chains, dot ecosystems and other ecosystem?

Comment: XCM is how parachains communicate with others. I think the question needs to be a bit more specific about what kind of interaction (E.g. for fungible or non-fungible things?).

Answer (score 1):

Bit.Country uses XCM to communicate with other parachains in the ecosystem. There are quite a few use cases that have been implementing

- Transfer parachain native token from/to other parachains.
- Transfer non-fungible token from/to other parachains.